# SQL Server job step retry attempts for specific error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2008

I have a SQL job (4 steps job consist of SSIS packages) which runs on daily basis and extract data from various sources (source1, source2, source3) then it loads data to warehouse. Now my job fails due to 'Communication Link failure' with source1 at step 1.

Is there any way I can set up retry attempt SQL job based on this above error only.
For example, if I get error 'primary key violation' or some other data related issue then we should directly get notification that job failed but if we have error 'Communication Link failure' then step1 should do retry attempt.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, not with the SQL agent.

Longer answer: Maybe you can build up som logic where the package checks if the previous error was that specific error you're looking for, if then, execute again. Cumbersome but possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Event Handler for the `OnError` event with a Script Task which will check for this specific error and execute `msdb.dbo.sp_start_job` if this error occurred.  Since I'm not sure the exact error code you're getting, this only checks the `@[System::ErrorDescription]` system variable for the specific text using the `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` option to make this match case insensitive.  However I would strongly recommend finding the exact error code and using the `@[System::ErrorCode]` variable to verify this instead.  I'd also suggest only retrying the job a certain number of times or within a given time-frame to avoid excessive failures if this issue persists as well.

```
  string errorMsg = Dts.Variables["System::ErrorDescription"].Value.ToString();

  if (errorMsg.IndexOf("Communication Link failure", 0, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
  {
      string connString = @"YourConnectionString;";
      string startJobCmd = @"EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_START_JOB N'NameOfJobToRetry;";

      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
      {
          SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(startJobCmd, conn);
          conn.Open();

          sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try this and will let you all know the outcome. Thanks again for the help.